# Custom NSButtonCell black background

Tags: cocoa, colors, background, nsbuttoncell

I have a NSButtonCell (a checkbox) in a cell-based NSTableView. I try to set its background color to a semi-transparent color (used tor the rest of the row), but this color fades to black. If the row color has an alpha of zero, the background of the control appears solid black.

Is there a way to mimic transparency on white instead of this (probably) nil color which default to black (0,0,0) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use buttons' `layer` property instead since the [gradual NSCell deprecation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#X10_10Notes) introduced several years ago already.

```
self.wantsLayer = true
self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.CGColor
```

It's much more easier than messing with a `drawRect(:)`-method.